# Magento2: How to get guest email address in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, email, logging

Please, how to get **guest** email address in **checkout**?

Comment: I think you want to say that customer come to your site without login . then you need him/his email address from browser's  session like this ?
Dose this customer visit your site earlier or first time user?

Comment: yes exactly  , i want to get guest email

Comment: You want to get it using js?

Comment: no i want to get it using PHP on my configProvider

Comment: You can't get guest customer email, before customer fill it. Then customer set email in related field, you can get it from input and send to server to store it where you need.

Answer (score 10):

In your **custom-method.js** file

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
],
function ($,quote,Component,) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            template: 'Namespace_ModuleName/custompayment/form_template'
        },

        getGuestEmail: function () {
            return quote.guestEmail;
        }

    });
}
);
```

After that just call that function you will get guest email address
If you want register customer email address then use following:

```
        getEmail: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.customerData.email;
        }
```

Comment: Yes your solution works fine for me

Comment: It is so cool to get this window.checkoutConfig array with almost everything we can ever need.

Comment: I place an order a guest user, In my case i need that given email id in payment page, i tried the above code but it's giving null. any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using javascript in checkout page using below method,

```
if(!window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.customer_id){
  var getGuestEmail = window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.customer_email;
  alert(getGuestEmail);
}
```

Using above code you can get guest email id. I haven't check with php methods.

Answer (score 0):

- In case of the Guest customer, magento didn't map email id to
  shipping or billing address before place order.
- In my case, I need guest email which is provided at the time of
  shipping page. To validate Guest email with Coupon code using this
  event ( salesrule_validator_process ) .

To Do that :
Step 1: Create di.xml to override core code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Custom\Couponfriend\Model\AccountManagement" />
</config>
```

Step 2: Override model in custom module, and set email to
    Quote's->shipping object. and get where you need it.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Couponfriend\Model;

class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement {

    public function isEmailAvailable($customerEmail, $websiteId = null) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $shippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/guestFriendsFamily.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('------------');

        try {
            if ($shippingAddress) {
                $shippingAddress->setData('email', $customerEmail);
                $shippingAddress->save();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if ($websiteId === null) {
                $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            }
            $this->customerRepository->get($customerEmail, $websiteId);
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

You can override constructor to create cart object using dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

This work for Magento 1

```
<?php 
       class Exinent_Billingtax_Model_Observer 
       {
            public function autoRegisterBilling($evt){
                if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
                    $data =$evt->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($data);
                $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                $email = $data['email'];
                $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $pwd = $data['customer_password'];
                $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);

                if (!$customer->getId()) {
                     //Code begins here for new customer registration
                    $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
                    $customer->setStore($store);
                    $customer->firstname = $data['firstname'];
                    $customer->lastname = $data['lastname'];
                    $customer->setEmail($email);
                    $customer->setPassword($pwd);
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');  
                    $customer->save();
                       }
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId()); // to login that customer.
               }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get guest and customer other information in you custom js like customerinfo.js in Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    ],
    function ($,Component,quote,placeOrderAction) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: 'Company_Module/custompayment/form_template'
            },

            getEmail: function () {
                if(quote.guestEmail) return quote.guestEmail;
                else return window.checkoutConfig.customerData.email;
            },

            getLastName: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().lastname;
            },

            getFirstName: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().firstname;
            },

            getAddress: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().street[0]+", "+quote.billingAddress().postcode+" "+quote.billingAddress().city+", Maroc";
            },

            getPhone: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().telephone;
            },

        });
    }
);
```