# Magento2 : How to get guest email address after shipping address and before placeorder?

Tags: magento2, quote, billing-address, magento-2.0.9

I am making a payment method. After clicking Place Order Button from checkout in custom payment method controller file I am getting the quote object will all billing and shipping data.

In that, I am not getting the guest email address. Also at that time email address is not saved in DB in address table.

> **How do I get the guest email address after shipping address and before
>   place order ?**

I am using my custom controller, in this the code is :

```
 $quote = $this->getQuote();
 //get Email to set for guest user
 if ($quote->getCustomerEmail()) {
     $email = $quote->getCustomerEmail();
 } elseif ($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()) {
     $email = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
 } else {
     $email = '';
 }
```

Comment: Can you please paste you code what you have tried? Thanks with file name & path

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/magento2-how-to-get-guest-email-address-in-checkoutphp-way

Comment: Where do you need to retrieve it? In a model, block, API interface?

Comment: @RiccardoT in controller file I am looking for it.

Comment: @Ashish Jagnani: Hi Ashish, i'm experiencing the same trouble, how did you solve this? I need to get the guest email address in a plugin (or overriding) the module \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
private $session;
...
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    ...
    $this->session = $session;
}
...
public function execute()
{
    ...
    $customerEmail = $this->session->getLastRealOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
    ...
}
...
```

if you need it before order place you can use:

```
$this->session->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need Guest user email. except email I am getting all data of guest user from `$quote->getBillingAddress();`, but not email. Also when I am checking the DB of quote address table, email field is blank at that time.

Comment: Try getting it from shipping address.

Comment: Both billing and shipping address have same data in DB and no email !

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to get the guest user's email using `$quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()` you need first set it in the payment information.

If you have a look at paypal's module in view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method.js you can see:

```
        if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/set-payment-information', {
                cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
            });
            payload = {
                cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
                email: quote.guestEmail,
                paymentMethod: paymentData
            };
            method = 'post';
```

Setting the email and calling the set-payment-information allows you to get the email using `$quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()` in the next steps as paypal's module does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
    $customerSession->getCustomerId();
    $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer();
    $customerSession->getCustomerData();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
}else{
    $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Its not working, also the above link of accepted answer is also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please use two plugin. Following code worked for me

```
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="BA_Vertex_ShippingInformationManagement" type="BA\Vertex\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="BA_IsCustomerAvailable" type="BA\Vertex\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementPlugin"/>
</type>
```

AccountManagementInterface

```
<?php
namespace BA\Vertex\Plugin\Magento\Customer\Api;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class AccountManagementPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $cartHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
        RequestInterface $request,
        RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }
    public function beforeIsEmailAvailable(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
        $result,
        $customerEmail,
        $websiteId = null
    ) {
        $referrer = $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
        if (preg_match('/checkout/i', $referrer)) {
            $this->cartHelper->getQuote()->setCustomerEmail($result);
            $this->cartHelper->getQuote()->save();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

ShippingInformationManagement

```
    <?php
namespace BA\Vertex\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\Model;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $_logger;
   /**
    * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
    */
    protected $cartHelper;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper
    ) {
        $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $emailAddress = $this->cartHelper->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail();
        $firstName = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname();
        $lastName = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();
   
        return $result;
    }
}
```