# Magento 2 : How to disable COD payment method for specific users?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, user, cash-on-delivery

I have Magento 2.3.1 and **I want to disable the** **cash on delivery (COD) method for specific users on the checkout page.**

I have a list of users as email Ids. **I want to prevent that all email ids from checkout**. I want to develop the functionality for all users guests or logged-in. I have all the emails in the backend with comma-separated values.

If anyone of them tries to checkout by selecting the COD method it will disable that method and not allow them to checkout.

Does anyone have any idea ? please share with me.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313052/magento-2-hide-payment-method-if-company-name-field-got-a-value/313064#313064

Comment: in observer get the current customer  and based on your requirement add your condition

Comment: Hi, @Devidas your code is correct when the user is logged in but what about the guest user?

Comment: get the guest email address in the checkout page

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150393/magento2-how-to-get-guest-email-address-after-shipping-address-and-before-plac